# Messages not received

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket

So I have a spring boot backend and react client i am trying to make a chat application.
So this is my problem, lets say I have two user UserA and UserB

> UserA sends a message, the backend receives the messages and saves it on the database,

this is my code for backend:

```
 @RestController
 public class MessageController {

private final MessageService messageService;

MessageController(final MessageService messageService){
    this.messageService = messageService;
}

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/message")
@SendTo("/chatroom/public")
public Message receiveMessage(@Payload Message message){
    return message;
}

@MessageMapping("/private-message")
public Message recMessage(@Payload Message message){
    System.out.println(message);
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(String.valueOf(message.getReceiverId()),"/private",message);
    messageService.saveMessage(message, message.getSenderId(), message.getReceiverId());
    return message;
}
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chatroom", "/user");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
}


public class Message {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long messageId;
private String content;
private String date;
private MessageType type;
@ManyToOne
private User sender;
private long senderId;
private long receiverId;
@ManyToOne
private User receiver;
private Boolean deleted;
```

}

and this is my react  code

```
var stompClient = null;

const ChatArea = (props) => {
const senderId = useSelector((state) => state.senderId);
const receiverId = useSelector((state) => state.receiverId);
const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const fetchMessages = async () => {
  const msgs = await loadMessages(senderId, receiverId);
  setChatMessages(msgs);
};

fetchMessages();
connectWebSocket();
}, []);

const connectWebSocket = () => {
const socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

stompClient.connect({}, () => {
  console.log("WebSocket connected");

  // Call the subscription function for private messages
  subscribeToPrivateMessageEndpoint();
});

return stompClient;
};

// Call these functions to subscribe to the endpoints when needed
// subscribeToMessageEndpoint();
// subscribeToPrivateMessageEndpoint();

 const subscribeToMessageEndpoint = () => {
stompClient.connect({}, () => {
  stompClient.subscribe("/chatroom/public", (message) => {
    // Handle public message received
    const messageData = JSON.parse(message.body);
    console.log("Received public message:", messageData);
  });
});
};

const subscribeToPrivateMessageEndpoint = () => {
const endpoint = `/user/${receiverId}/private`;
console.log(endpoint);

  stompClient.connect({}, () => {
  stompClient.subscribe(endpoint, (message) => {
    // Handle private message received
    const messageData = JSON.parse(message.body);
    // setChatMessages(...chatMessages, messageData);
    console.log("Received private message:", messageData);
  });
 });
 };

  // Function to send a private message
  const sendPrivateMessage = (content) => {
  const messageDto = {
  messageId: 0, // Set to 0 or leave it out if you don't have a messageId yet
  content: content,
  date: new Date().toISOString(), // Use the current date/time or format as needed
  type: "CHAT", // Assuming you want to specify it as a private message
  sender: null, // Set to null or leave it out if not applicable
  receiver: null, // Set to null or leave it out if not applicable
  deleted: false, // Default to false
  senderId: senderId, // Your sender's ID
  receiverId: receiverId, // Receiver's ID
};

stompClient.send("/app/private-message", {}, JSON.stringify(messageDto));
};

return (
<div className={classes.chatArea}>
  <div className={classes.head}>
    <FriendImage image={props.user.profileImage} />
    <h3>
      {props.user.firstName} {props.user.lastName}
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div className={classes.chats}>
    {chatMessages.map((message, index) => (
      <PrivateMessage key={index} message={message} />
    ))}
  </div>
  <ChatInput onClick={sendPrivateMessage} />
</div>
);
};
export default ChatArea;
```

i want to fix the messsage not receiving by the receiver of the message